# After Changing Permisions, Plesk,Root,Mysql is Down

Tags: root, chown

i have connected on Root with SSH Access.

Becouse i transfer the files with root, all files was root own. I need it to be on other user, so i was connected on as my current folder:
var/www/vhosts/mypage/httpdocs/

I have posted this command:
chown -R extius /

The changes was done, and after i got:
https://mypage.myserver.net:8443
500 - Internal Server Error !

**I just see, that i have reset all files to my username, including root files.
Now i can't connect on the root, how i can fix this?**

Also, i can't connect on root. Can you fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: no, your system is screwed. You will need physical access, but even then there is a great chance that the only thing you will be able to do is extract files with a live disk.

The best thing to do is to restore your backups.

Comment: So, anyway did there is possible my hosting provider to get fix this problem with changing all files permisions to root? Thanks

Comment: no, not a chance.

Comment: So what is the best in this case? To get all files and to reinstall the server? Then to upload at all?

Comment: If you made the mistake of not making backups, yes.

Comment: @Seik Yeah, it's probably worth just reinstalling. A very good sysadmin could revive the machine by resetting privileges with the package management system and then adjusting errors from there, but that might take many hours of work. Unless it's worth at least $500, start a new system and copy files. When you're done with that, install bacula and copy your files offsite.

Comment: I'm very sad about this, with 1 command i have crashed my server. I will try to get my files back and to start uploading all agian from begin. Thanks to all.

Comment: I'd suggest paying very close attention to what you are doing with each command until you have a good grasp of each. Things do not work the same way in Linux as they do in Windows. And I'd suggest not doing so much as root. You have immense power to completely goof up your servers when root.

Comment: I found a solution. I started my server in recovory mode, wich means i can get all files on the server, including and databases. I didn't know did in recovory mode if i change the permisions, the same will be effected when i turn it off.